# How to open an archive file in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to open an archive(.zip) file in eclipse like this

[image]

My situation: when i try to import an existing android project it can display as follow:

[image]

How to include "Select archive file option" in eclipse environment?. Any Suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey Buddy take a Visual look of this:-

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NMfIHuEwE7A

If you will face any further problem. Then let me know..

Edit:-

Try leaving the project folder outside of the workspace during the import.

When you re-import the project, check the "copy project files into workspace" box.

In my experience, manually copying projects into (or out of) the workspace can be troublesome.

Comment: Hey bro..This is the video to convert Android Project into zip and then open that zip into eclipse as zip file. But in my Eclipse, i dont have that option to "Select as achive file"

Comment: @Yati, which eclipse version are you using. And see my edited answer.

Comment: Got It.I import project as Android Project. To have zip file, Import project as General Project..